# Cannot access STL C++ container values with GDB

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

I am debugging C++ code and I have problems when trying to access to an std::list.
The problem is that I cannot get the address associated to the head node ($3 refers to the list):

```
p $3._M_impl._M_node
$21 = {
    _M_next = 0x240ee70, 
    _M_prev = 0x240ee70
}
```

I get the following error message when I try to get the head node address:

(gdb) p &($3._M_impl._M_node)

Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.

I also have tried with the STL extension available from the Internet and it also fails at the same point.

```
set $head = &$arg0._M_impl._M_node
```

I have looked at Google an this is all I can find about the problem:

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gdb.devel/9496

But it doesn't solve my problem. Any suggestions are more than welcomed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, this particular list is clearly empty. If this is all you have of the list I could imagine that its entire value is held in registered e.g. while it is passed on (returned or passed as argument).

Comment: You were right I did't realise that the list is empty.


But even if the list is empty, the head node should be there, I should be able to get its address. 

I have tried a small example consisting of creating a list and adding some elements. Then I have defined two breakpoints: one after adding the elements and the other after clearing the list. In both cases I can get the head node address.

Comment: Personally, I would hope that an empty list which is passed to another function actually isn't necessarily "there"! I would hope it is just a few pointers in some registers which don't make it to memory for now...

Comment: If you compiled your code with just about any level of optimization, I would not be surprised that your pointers of an empty list are in registers.  Try compiling without optimization and see if gdb reports the content.

Comment: Hi Bill. The code was compiled using the following options: -O0 -g. I don't know if I still have to enable/disable more flags. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dietmar, the list is an attribute and the object still exists. That is, it hasn't been destroyed when I try to retrieve the head node address.

Comment: Take a look at stl-views (http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport).